# Difference between starting a detached task and calling a nonisolated func in main actor

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

Imagine I'm in a class annotated with `@MainActor` so that all the functions are tied to the main actor. I'm trying to understand what the difference is between doing the following:

```
func bar() {
  Task.detached(priority: .background) {
    await foo()
  }
}

func foo() async {
  ...
}
```

vs

```
func bar() {
  Task(priority: .background) {
    await foo()
  }
}

nonisolated func foo() async {
  ...
}
```

Are they the same?

Comment: Well, in terms of "what actor would the execution of `foo` be isolated to", it is the same in both cases, but there might be other aspects of this that I did not consider. Also note that if `foo` is `nonisolated` then it *could* be run on non-main threads, by some other code.

Comment: Wait, isn’t `foo` running on a non Main thread in my examples?

Comment: Nope. In your first example, `foo` is isolated to the main actor because it is inside a class bearing the `@MainActor` declaration. It doesn’t matter that it was called from a detached task that is not on the main actor; the first `foo` will still run on the main actor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> Imagine I'm in a class annotated with `@MainActor` so that all the
> functions are tied to the main actor. I'm trying to understand what
> the difference is between doing the following:
>
> ```swift
> func bar() {
>   Task.detached(priority: .background) {
>     await foo()
>   }
> }
>
> func foo() async {
>   ...
> }
> ```

The `bar` method creates a non-structured task, which, because it is a `detached` task, is not on the current actor. But that task will `await` the `foo` method, which *will* run on the main actor. The fact that `foo` is in a class bearing the `@MainActor` designation means that it is isolated to that actor, regardless of which Swift concurrency context you invoke it.

But, in this case, there is little point in launching a detached task that only awaits an actor-isolated function.

You continue:

> vs
>
> ```swift
> func bar() {
>   Task(priority: .background) {
>     await foo()
>   }
> }
>
> nonisolated func foo() async {
>   ...
> }
> ```

In this case, `bar` will launch a task on the current (main) actor, but it will await the result of `foo`, which is nonisolated (i.e., not isolated to the main actor).

So, the difference is that the first example, `foo` is actor-isolated, but it is not in the second example.

Comment: So if I wanted to run foo from a Non main thread I’d need to use the second way but with a detached task?

Comment: Yep, detached task and function that is nonisolated or use separate actor.